# JOOMLA JToolBarHelper в самописном компоненте

Tags: joomla3

Как использовать JToolBarHelper::addNew() немогу найти информацию...
Добавил в view.html.php

в виде

```
protected function addToolBar()
{
    JToolBarHelper::addNew('doptsi.add');
}
```

tmpl/edit.php у меня есть...

кнопка создать появилась...
но выдает только ошибку в консоли
Only Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'task' of null...

Please help

Comment: This is a resource for the Russian language community. Please write a question in Russian or go to the English language resource.

Comment: Перевел на русский